# setState call inside a custom hook is not updating the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, closures, react-hooks

I'm trying to set up a basic custom hook to return the device orientation in React Native. I have an example of functional code right beside this and I can't figure out why this won't work. I think it's a closure/scoping issue of some sort but clearly I don't know.

I know there are easier ways of getting the device orientation, but I want to know why this isn't working and how to make it work.

Current behavior: calling `setOrientation` does not change the value of `orientation`.
Expected behavior: calling `setOrientation` updates the value of `orientation`.

Once this happens I think the hook will work properly, since it returns `null` every time `Dimensions` updates.

[UPDATE: edited for clarity]

````
import { Dimensions, } from 'react-native';

function useDeviceDimensions() {

  const [orientation, setOrientation] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const setDimensions = (e) => {
      console.log('running', orientation); // null
      const {width, height} = e.window;
      setOrientation(width > height ? 'landscape' : 'portrait');
    };

    Dimensions.addEventListener('change', setDimensions);

    return () => Dimensions.removeEventListener('change', setDimensions);
  }, [])

  return orientation;
}

export default useDeviceDimensions;```
````

Comment: The properties of the object the `useDeviceDimensions` function returns will never be changed, and that has nothing to do with React. Is just because you never mutate the returned object, you redefine some of the variables it contains.

Comment: Can only guess here, what you mean by "this isn't working" - `orientation` should work fine. You don't update/invoke `setWidth` and `setHeight` on dimension change.

Comment: @Titus can you elaborate? I don't understand how my code would redefine the state variables instead of updating them.

Comment: @ford04 please see updated code - I took the unused bits out so it's clearer what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What I'm saying is that by the looks of it you're using the return value of `useDeviceDimensions`, if that is the case, this return value (`orientation`) won't change if you redefine it inside the function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Your example works ...

`setOrientation` will actually change the state value of `orientation` and `useDeviceDimensions` will return the changed `orientation`. The issue is rather where you placed the `console.log` statement - and you are right, that is related to the closure (and its scope) passed to `useEffect`.

`useEffect` is invoked [only once](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) with your defined callback. This callback is a closure and can access `orientation` from `useState`. At the time of the closure creation, `orientation` variable will have the value `null`. Because there is never a new closure created (`[]` dependencies in `useEffect`), it will always print the value `null`, when the contained change listener is triggered.

However, `setOrientation` inside `setDimensions` will dispatch and communicate the change to React. The flow is like this:

1. The `useEffect` closure is invoked once on first render.
2. Sometime later a `change` event is triggered.
3. `setDimensions` inside your closure always prints the same value from the function outer scope `orientation` variable (which at construction time has value `null`).
4. `setOrientation` is invoked, React internally updates the state and triggers a new render cycle in the parent component.
5. `useDeviceDimensions` is invoked again from the parent component, it now has and returns the new `orientation` state.
6. A new change is triggered, go on with 3 again.

Point 4 works in the closure, because React has an internal list of “memory cells” for each component, where it can read and update the recent state, so updates work across the closure scope (see [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-does-react-associate-hook-calls-with-components) for more info). The read side `orientation` is a stale variable, if you will, that just has a reference to the first state value, that React stored initially.

#### ... but better declare `useEffect` in a safe way

Your `useEffect` hook uses state you don't mention in its dependencies array. What React docs say concerning this:

> If you use this optimization, make sure the array includes all values from the component scope (such as props and state) that change over time and that are used by the effect. Otherwise, your code will reference stale values from previous renders. [Link](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects)

So if you also want to use `orientation` in `useEffect`, you could declare it as dependency:

```
 useEffect(() => {
  ...
  }, [orientation]);
```

Have a look at this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-chandrasekhar-tn3c1) for an example, hope it clarifies things a bit!